# Ajax on Exposed View Filter with Better Exposed Filter Module

Tags: views

I have a filter exposed as a block and would like to filter my view via ajax instead of refreshing the page. I installed the Better Exposed Filter module, set the view's Ajax setting to TRUE, and set the style to Better Exposed Filters but the page still refreshes.

According to the [Better Exposed Filter's documentation](https://www.drupal.org/node/766974#instant-filter) all I need to do is add some javascript but that didn't work.